# Onclick function is not defined

Tags: jquery

I have this fairly simple function that I want to call with `onclick=""`. No matter what I do, I get the error `Function is not defined`.

html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="shareURL(); return false;" data-share="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" href="#">Share on Facebook</a>
```

js:

```
function shareURL() {
  var $url = window.location.href;
  var $src = $(this).data("share");
  $url = encodeURI($url);
  if ($src) {
    window.location.href = $url + $src;
  }
}
```

The function resides inside document ready, like in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3vwc0sp2/7/).

Comment: Try it like this, then it works.https://jsfiddle.net/3vwc0sp2/8/

Comment: Have you add jquery ?

Comment: In your fiddle, you have `on ready` wrapper, change to `no-wrapper - head`

Comment: Read up on `scope`.  Your `shareURL` function is *only defined* within the scope of document.ready - it's not visible outside that scope, it not visible to `onclick=`.   If you used jquery to wire-up the events as recommended, then this would also happen inside the doc.ready so would find the function as they are in the same scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put your shareURL Method outside of the `$(document).ready{function()}`, please consider following examples for more details.

> below example works fine as i have put shareURL Method outside of the
>   document.ready method

```js
function shareURL() {
  var $url = window.location.href;
  var $src = $(this).data("share");
  $url = encodeURI($url);
  console.log("method called!");
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="shareURL(); return false;" data-share="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" href="#">Share on Facebook</a>
```

> below will not work as scope of share url is limited to document.ready
>   method

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function shareURL() {
    //this will not work as scope of the function is limited to document
    var $url = window.location.href;
    var $src = $(this).data("share");
    $url = encodeURI($url);
    console.log("this method will never called and gives you error Uncaught ReferenceError: shareURL is not defined");
    if ($src) {
      window.location.href = $url + $src;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="shareURL(); return false;" data-share="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" href="#">Share on Facebook</a>
```